Determine if for each b ∈ R4 , there exists an x ∈ R3 such that T(x) = b.



From my understanding, the nullity + rank of the row reduced matrix should equal the dimension of the domain of the transformation in order for the statement "for each b ∈ R4 , there exists an x ∈ R3 such that T(x) = b" to be true, in this case 3. My first question is, is this the correct understanding of how to solve this problem?
If my understanding is correct, my second question is why would I have to do any math at all for this question? Since the nullity-rank theorem states that the the nullity + rank = the number of columns of a matrix, and we have 3 columns, then we know the nullity + rank = 3 and the dimension of the domain is also 3. In that case, we know that in fact for each b ∈ R4 , there exists an x ∈ R3 such that T(x) = b.

As a teacher, I wonder how they justify that this question is worth 25 points. Like, what is the difference between a 16 point answer and a 17 point answer?

I thought you were on the right track,  but then you gave the opposite to the answer I was expecting.
Indeed, by rank-nullity,  the rank cannot exceed $3.$
Thus the column space,  which is the image,  has dimension at most $3.$
But $\Bbb R^4$ has dimension $4.$
So the answer is no.
A linear transformation can never increase the dimension of the domain space.
Thus the actual definition for the linear transformation here is nothing but a red-herring.

Or just by the theorem that the row rank equals the column rank.  The rank is at most $3.$

So rank-nullity should be equal to the dimension of the codomain of the transformation in order for the answer to be yes?

Pretty much.   More precisely,  there can never be a surjective linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^{n+k}, k\gt0.$
